Contacts.app misbehaving in Sequoia on M1 iMac
iMac 24” M1 2021, macOS Sequoia 15.1.1, Contacts v. 14.0
purchased from the Apple Store Refurbished January 18, 2024
Since updating my partner’s iMac a few weeks ago, Contacts is misbehaving:
New lists can be created within Contacts, and populated by dragging individual contacts from the “All Contacts” list and dropping them onto the new list name. On this machine, however, this usually works only for adding three or four names. After that, dragging a contact onto the new list name has no effect at all on the new list name (that is, the list name doesn’t change color or highlight), and the new list, when opened, does not include the unsuccessfully-just-dragged Contacts entry.
What I’ve tried:
• Quit and relaunched Contacts. Temporary improvement only
• Restarted the computer. Temporary improvement only
• booted into Safe Mode. Misbehavior continues after reboot
• run Apple Diagnostics to make sure the hardware is OK. It’s OK.
• reloaded macOS using local Recovery. Temporary improvement only
After doing any one (or more) of these, Contacts behaves correctly for another small number of drag-and-drops, and then fails again in the same manner. In all other respects, Contacts behaves correctly.
Multiple complains now appear in the Apple Community about Sequoia contacts not synching. The problem on my machine, however, doesn’t seem to be related to iCloud synch, as the new list including the contacts I’ve been able to add (as well as the entire “All Contacts” list) appears correctly both on the synched iPhone and also on the iCloud web page.
The machine is still under AppleCare+, but I’d like to find and rectify a cause, rather than spending time on the phone with Apple Support, or physically returning the computer to Apple or to an Apple Store.
Any ideas?

When you refer to "temporary improvement," what does that mean exactly? It works for a while, and then spontaneously stops working? When it's not working, can you delete items from lists? Also, can you create "On My Mac" lists that don't sync to iCloud? Also, is the iPhone affected in the same way? Can you create lists on the iCloud website and populate them?

@LincDavis Thanks for your questions. I'll be able to sit down with the computer tomorrow or Monday, and will get back to you here with answers.

@LincDavis Re: “temporary improvement”? As described above: works for perhaps 2 to 5 changes to the new list, then spontaneously stops working. Re: when not working, can items be deleted from lists? Yes, items can be deleted from any list. Re: create “on my Mac” lists w/o synch? No, “on my Mac” is and was not available. As to synching: either all Contacts and Contact lists synch via iCloud, or none does. Re: Is the iPhone affected? No changes there. iOS 18.1.1 allows adding and deleting lists, and also allows the user to add or delete contacts from a list. Those changes continue to work...

...Re: Create lists on the iCloud website and populate them? Yes, that works correctly, and does not periodically fail.

Please quit Contacts if it's running. Navigate in the Finder to the folder ~/Library/Application Support/AddressBook in your home folder. The user Library folder is hidden by default, but you can get to it by copying the above path and pasting it into the Finder's Go > Go to Folder... dialog. Move the folder to the Desktop, then launch Contacts. Initially you'll have no contacts; don't panic. After a minute or two all iCloud contacts should repopulate. Test. If it works now, you can delete the folder you moved to the Desktop.

@LincDavis Thanks again. I'm (again) in another place, but should be able to give this a try tomorrow afternoon or evening.

@LincDavis I followed your instructions. Then I moved individual Contacts in and out of the suspect Contacts list, singly and in groups, for several minutes. Contacts.app worked correctly, and didn't fail. Looks like there was a corruption in the iMac's AddressBook file, which was eliminated when the iCloud Contacts data was used to reconstitute the AddressBook file. I'll come back to this tonight or tomorrow, and confirm. If it still behaves, I will cheerfully invite you to offer this as an Answer, which I will happily upvote and accept. Thank you!

@LincDavis Contacts continues to function normally. I very much appreciate your successful Rx. Please present it as an Answer, and I will happily accept it.

The OP reports that he solved the problem by taking the steps below. You must be connected to the Internet for this to work. Back up all data before making any changes.

Quit Contacts if it's running.

Navigate in the Finder to the folder ~/Library/Application Support/AddressBook in your home folder. The user Library folder is hidden by default, but you can get to it by copying the above path and pasting it into the Finder's Go > Go to Folder... dialog. Move the folder to the Desktop.

Launch Contacts. At first, you'll have no contacts. Don't panic. After a minute or two all iCloud contacts should repopulate. Test. If Contacts works now, you can delete the folder you moved to the Desktop.


